# Why does std::transform and similar cast the 'for' loop increment to (void)?

Tags: c++

What is the purpose of `(void) ++__result` in the code below?

Implementation for std::transform:

```
// std::transform
template <class _InputIterator, class _OutputIterator, class _UnaryOperation>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
_OutputIterator
transform(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _OutputIterator __result, _UnaryOperation __op)
{
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first, (void) ++__result)
        *__result = __op(*__first);
    return __result;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the people who write style guides really think this code would be clearer if the author had written `static_cast<void>(++__result)`...

Answer (score 107):

It is possible to overload `operator,`. Casting either operand to `void` prevents any overloaded operator from being called, since overloaded operators cannot take `void` parameters.

Comment: Wow. This would never have occured to me.

Comment: @Angew there are lots of these.  For more fun, read [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/1tedni/notsocommon_pitfalls_of_c_xpost_rcplusplus/ce7bqnu) by STL, a Microsoft compiler engineer.

Comment: In a similar vein, you'll see copious use of `addressof` or equivalent in the standard library instead of unary `&`.

Comment: So is it possible to have a class provide an `operator void()` ?

Comment: @JDługosz Ha. Yeah, a class can provide that, but it won't be used. A conversion to `void` will always just discard the value without looking at which conversion operators are available. The only way to call such an operator is with an explicit `expr.operator void()` call.

Comment: @T.C. perhaps a macro  `STD_SEQUENCE(++__first, ++__result)` could act as a readible form, much like `std::addressof`?

Comment: @T.C. grep..? Bikeshed the name

Comment: or `std::who_made_comma_overloadable`

Answer (score 7):

It avoids call of overloaded `operator,` if there is any. Because the type `void` can't be an argument of a function (operator).

Another approach would be inserting `void()` in the middle:

```
++__first, void(), ++__result
```